# Is there a Node.js data store that doesn't need to be installed for a small project that works on both *NIX and Windows?

Tags: node.js

I have a small project that I was using [node-dirty](/questions/tagged/node-dirty) for, but it's not really for production use and I've had way to many surprises with it so I would like to switch. I was looking at using [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite), but compiling a client for it seems troublesome. Is there something like [node-dirty](/questions/tagged/node-dirty) (i.e. a pure Node.js implementation of a data store), but that's more suited for a small project that doesn't have more than a few hundred sets of data. I've faced the following problems with [node-dirty](/questions/tagged/node-dirty) that I would expect an altenrative data store not  to do:

- Saving a Date object makes it come out as a string when reloading the data (but during execution it remains a Date object). I'm fine with having to serialize the Date object myself, as long as I get out the same thing it lets me put into it.
- Iterating over data and deleting something in the same forEach loop makes the iteration stop.
- My client is reporting deleted data re-appearing and I've intermittently seen this too, I have no idea why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How much data do you have?  For some projects it's reasonable to just have things in memory and persist them by dumping a JSON file with all the data.

Comment: Very little, the data isn't more than a few MB as the client explicitly said did not want their data archived so it won't grow. I may go down this route.

Answer (score -2):

Just use npm to install a NoSQL module like redis or mongodb.

Comment: This requires that Redis or MongoDB is installed on the machine, which is what he's trying to avoid.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to bundle both the client and the data store in one package. Btw, there doesn't seem to be a production ready instance of redis for windows. MongoDB would seem like the better option if I went down this route.

Comment: @Brandon, you are right. I mention the npm route because once you have node, then you can install the DB easily. However, if Kit wants to (1) deliver the code all in one bundle without subsequent install steps, then for small sets of data, you can use the fs api: http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/file-system/how-to-store-local-config-data